# PowerShell script to find registry key

Tags: powershell

i need some help, i want to create a powershell script that searches the registry for just the key RebootRequired, no value or data search is needed.
with a IF find create a txt file named RebootRequired.txt in folder C:\Candi\

is that even possible?

been trying out some scripting, but i can barley make the script to find the key if it present within the registry.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Show us your code!

Comment: Will you need to run it against locally or remotely ? On a single or multiple computers ? What version of PowerShell can you use ? As soon as you post some sample code you will see answers popping ^_^ here people don't _usually_ write blind code : )

Comment: @sodawillow sometimes I can't help it :(

Comment: I think I had noticed this ^^ Can't help being helpful, huh ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve all keys with `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` and then filter on key names with `Where-Object`.

The `Registry` provider is a little different from the `FileSystem` provider, in that the `Name` property of each item is the entire key path (ie. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft` instead of just `Microsoft`). You can use `PSChildName` to refer to the leaf name:

```
if(@(Get-ChildItem HKLM: -Recurse |Where-Object {$_.PSChildName -eq 'RebootRequired'}))
{
  # Something was returned! Create the file
  New-Item C:\Candi\RebootRequired.txt -ItemType File
}
```

You can suppress error messages from inaccessible keys with the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` parameter argument with `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: Thank you very much! :) it works perfect :)
would it be more effective if i specify the path a bit more? i know the Key "spawns" in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\

//Best regards

Comment: i just now need to set the script to have permissions to search HKLM :)

//Best Regards